# Keycloak and Google login

Tags: spring, spring-boot, authentication, keycloak

Currently I am developing Spring Boot application which need to have Keycloak login. I managed to make Google registration and when I get registered I getting this response:

```
{
"access_token": "ya29.dJnTYLwF7cBoJOHal1-8Efn9sw6oacGhA_JLiruKk2jOqBgPpKa1gSmFferDvj-1D2mYg_jxEHUMVatz8z-F3L4e5A8l_AixFeRPmg4C_nnA--Pdvxwl1moglBbwjaJTJTUmE4yh1PzPnbBiZ",
"token_type": "Bearer",
"expires_in": "3599",
"id_token": "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6Ijc0MjE3YjhkYWRiYjM2NTc4MzU4MGY5ZTkyNDg3ZDTYiLCJ0eXAiOiJKV1QifQ.eyJpc3MiOiJhY2NvdW50cy5nb29nbGUuY29tIiwiYXpwIjoiODY5Njc1Nzc0MjgxLTY4ZmExbjY3ZW41NW5zb3YyaGdib2JtZG05c3VlMDB1LmFwcHMuZ29vZ2xldXNlcmNvbnRlbtIiwiYXVkIjoiODY5Njc1Nzc0MjgxLTY4ZmExbjY3ZW41NW5zb3YyaGdib2JtZG05c3VlMDB1LmFwcHMuZ29vZ2xldXNlcmNvbnRlbnQuY29tIiwic3ViIjoiMTAxNDE4ODQ2MDM0MzI5Nzk0ODcwIiwiZW1haWwiOiJtYXJpbnNwYWppYzE5OThAZ21haWwuY29tIiwiZW1haWxfdmVyaWZpZWQiOnRydWUsImF0X2hhc2giOiJlbno5VDhuc3NLSHNqaEdVbFZQV253IiwiaWF0IjoxNjMxNTUzNjAyLCJleHAiOjE2MzE1NTcyMDJ9.oU_LAWPQU0RJ5yMM7M-xtKdM1rpLy2xqIg46kHu0KWR_1_2IY_tc3Uf1v2nNoEAQVXnZVbScUaHspwNny8yDirybxgOX_73aPGzb_FmcjVqgLTZTt8dbjizgy412cNFskH3GuRAXRMZppDbPPKlE2sgceMxapboCuivXIRyAyDQ_uXHSINEaPKFE3Tqjx-x6T6epcqY8M4hCt8Obs929BT86e3Ky6Xj1DUBv5UMm1Hk8NxoD_JU-rFLPQx-FZrVV3kYkdbJWKpoUVU-CToXDR4yRmxYXoz2kZMlc-rgugxxJ3OKG-JotVfSDh5Vp5iHy9kUpHOxi_8vWKw28LwNNhA"
}
```

Now I have to take access token and other information from Keycloak by this tokens, but I really don't know which endpoint I have to shoot.
Is there some example of login with Google or some advice ? Thanks!

Comment: you have already `access_token`, no? Keycloak as I remember is doing all this magic for you - you need just properly confgure client

Comment: Yes, but this is Google access token which is not JWT.
 In normal login I have to pass those parameters on Keycloak: {"grant_type", "client_id", "username", "password", "client_secret"} 
Probably Keycloak can do magic from that token but I don't know how to send it properly if you get me. What would be name of parameter instead username and password so I can sent it to Keycloak? "name" "acces_token_value"

Comment: You need to configure Keycloak identity brokering with Google - https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/#_identity_broker

Comment: Yup, I have configured identity broker in Keycoak. And what I didn't mention, I am looking for Keycloak API for authorization by Google token. After I registered user using Google I have to allow him to login. From Frontend I can get those tokens and I need to validate them and return Keycloak access token. I need Endpoint in Keycloak where I can send those values like normal username-password endpoint which is: "http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/realm_name/protocol/openid-connect/token".